# Border Line on last cell even if it is null/empty cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a problem in this part in creating a border line for each row to last cell.
it works well if the last cell has a value. but the border lines stop when the last cell is empty.

here's my code

```
lastcell = Cells(Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Address
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Row

Rng = "A11:" & lastcell
Range(Rng).Select
With Selection
    .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThin
    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThin
    .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThin
    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = True
End With
```

I want it to still add continuous border line until the last data value even if the last cell of the row is empty..

thank you.

Comment: You are looking for a value in column S to determine the lastrow. If it were blank it wouldn't be the lastrow. Perhaps you want to look at a different column for determining that?

Comment: how am I going to do it? since my last column is S. I've already tried to use "lastrow" instead of "lastcell" but it gives me error. I don't know what command will I going to use for it to continuously add border line even if the last cell is blank. I'm sorry I'm new at VBA macro

Comment: If S can be blank, but another cell will always have a value, such as A, then you can determine the lastrow by looking at A, but format S even if it is blank. Is that possibly true in this situation?